# Check if String xml is malformed before parsing it

Tags: java, xml

I'd like to create a method that gets String variable with XML content, check if the XML is malformed and if it is- returns True + Arraylist with sequential number.

So far, I'm using DOM parser that throws exception if the XML is malformed but it's not good for me because I want my code to keep running (I get KAFKA queue with XMLs and when 1 is malformed I want my code to pass to the next one).

Comment: Please add the exception log and your code to your question.

Comment: Well, **catch the exception** and continue with the next task.

Comment: If malformed xml is there most probably you would be getting SAXParserException catch the specific exception which you are getting and then proceed for the next one as mentioned in Thomas comment. And the same if you want you can maintain failed record list and if you would like to re-process those failed record you can retry

Comment: thanks for the answers. 
@Kulbhushan Singh hr  can you please explain how to proceed after catching exception? for now when I catch exception the code stops.

Comment: you have to show the code that you are trying.